# imagejpeg functions are not available

Tags: function, imagejpeg

I want to use imagejpeg function, but not working 
I use the code test it 
    ---------------
     if (function_exists('imagejpeg')) {
     echo "imagejpeg functions are available.
\n";
     } else {
     echo "imagejpeg functions are not available.
\n";
     }
     --------------
but got imagejpeg functions are not available.how to fix it ? thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: PHP language, sorry I forgot this